# How to check if row with such id presents in db in Access DB by MFC app

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc

I have the following window:

[image]

By this window I can insert new row to DB. But how can I check if row with such ID exists, as when I insert the row with the same ID my app crashes. Here's the code:

```
void CMikhailovskiiDBView::OnRecordAdd()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    m_pSet->AddNew();
    m_bAdding = TRUE;
    CEdit* pCtrl = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LibraryID);
    int result = pCtrl->SetReadOnly(FALSE);
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

By this method I am giving an access to ID edit as when I work with data (not insert row) this edit is read only. And here's the code of inserting to db method:

```
BOOL CMikhailovskiiDBView::OnMove(UINT nIDMoveCommand)
{
    if (m_bAdding) {
        m_bAdding = FALSE;
        UpdateData(TRUE);
        if (m_pSet->CanUpdate()){
            m_pSet->Update();
            m_pSet->Requery();
            UpdateData(FALSE);
            CEdit* pCtrl = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LibraryID);
            pCtrl->SetReadOnly(TRUE);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    else {
        return CRecordView::OnMove(nIDMoveCommand);
    }
}
```

So, I even don't understand where I should add validation for ID. I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose open a recordset with ID as filter criteria. If recordset is empty then ID does not exist. Is ID primary key? Isn't that supposed to be generated by table autonumber field?

Comment: By simply made an SELECT with the ID, if this SELECT return at least one row, you should no go further. (Of course, you can do this with a separate method).